# $E\left[Y|F^X_T\right]=E[Y|X_T]$? Reducing the conditional stopped sigma algebra in a natrual filtration setting.

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, stopping-times, filtrations

I have the following problem. A random variable $Y$ depends on $X_T$, where $X$ is a strong Markov process generating the filtration of the space, but not on what has happend earlier than $T$. ($Y$ is not independent of $X_T$, but independent of all $X_s 1_{s<T}$, where $s$ is in the real numbers.) Is there a way to show

$E\left[Y|F^X_T\right]=E[Y|X_T]$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "depends on $X_T$" ? Does $Y=f(X_T)$ ?

Comment: Oh yes, that was a bit misleading, thanks for asking.

Comment: I mean, that $Y$ is not independent of $X_T$, but independent of all $X_s 1_{s<T}$, where $s$ is in the real numbers. My idea was to go over $F^X_{T-}$, but, sadly, I couldn't really link it to $X$. I found out that, under some weak assumptions, one has  $F^X_T=\sigma(X_{s\wedge T})$, so I thought about $F^X_{T-}=\sigma(X_{(s\wedge T)-})$, but I couldn't find it anywhere and wasn't able to show.